# Solving $m\frac{\mathrm d ^2x}{\mathrm d t^2}+b\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}+kx=F_0\cos(\omega_dt)$ for $x(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am studying damped oscillations and forced oscillations in physics which are represented by the following differential equations in order.

$$\begin{align}m\dfrac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}+b\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}+kx&=0 \tag1\\m \dfrac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}+b\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}+kx&=F_0\cos(\omega_dt)\tag2\end{align}$$

I am not very much familiar with solving $2$nd order differential equations. I am able to solve equation $(1)$ by intuition. But solving equation $(2)$ seems complicated. It would be helpful if I could get a demonstration of the procedure to solving this type of ODE. Thanks

---

**Edit $1$**

I looked up the method of using Laplace transform to solving differential equations. I tried doing the first one using that.

**Attempt**

$$\begin{aligned}mx''(t)+bx'(t)+kx&=0\\ m\mathcal{L}\{x''\}+b\mathcal{L}\{x'\}+k\mathcal{L}\{x\}&=0\\ \mathcal{L}\{x\}&=A_0\frac{(ms+b)\sin\delta+m}{ms^2+bs-k}\end{aligned}$$

Is that right? Would now taking the inverse Laplace transform give me $x(t)=A_0e^{-bt/2m}\sin(\omega t+\delta)$ where $\omega^2=k/m-b^2/4m^2$? Thanks

Comment: +1 The particular solution for this kind of DE is $x(t)_p=A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$ if these arent part of the homogeneous solution ( equation 1). So it will depend on the values of the parameters $m,b,k$

Comment: Are $m,b,k$ constants? If so, do you know of the [method of undetermined coefficients](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx)? If not, then you could always apply the variation of parameters technique. Could you try the undetermined coefficients technique and see if you get stuck? The guess for the particular solution is given in the comment above.

Comment: @Axion004 Yes they are constant for a specific situation. I am not familiar with that, but thanks anyway. I'll look that up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laplace transform if you can. It is the easiest way of solving linear differential equations, I think.

Taking laplace transform of both sides, by noting that $X(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $x(t)$ and Laplace transform of the derivative of $x(t)$ is multiplication by $s$ in Laplace domain (if initial conditions are zero):

\begin{equation*}
ms^2X(s)+bsX(s)+kX(s)=F_0 L(cos(\omega_d t))=\frac{1}{2}F_0 L(e^{j \omega_d t} + e^{-j \omega_d t}) = \frac{1}{2}F_0(\frac{1}{s-j\omega_d}+\frac{1}{s+j\omega_d})
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
X(s) = \frac{1}{2}F_0 (\frac{1}{s-j\omega_d}+\frac{1}{s+j\omega_d}) \frac{1}{ms^2+bs+k}
\end{equation*}

(For finding the laplace of $e^{j\omega_d t}$, please see the first equation below).

From this point on, you know the Laplace transform $X(s)$. For finding the inverse Laplace transform, we decompose $X(s)$ into partial fractions, and then use Laplace table for primitive functions to find the inverse Laplace by inspection. Just look at the inverse Laplace of terms like $\frac{1}{s-a}$ or $\frac{1}{(s-a)^n}$ in the table, and note that Laplace transform is a linear transformation (that is you can do superposition). Here are the useful terms from the table:

\begin{equation*}
L^{-1}(\frac{c}{s+p})=ce^{-pt}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
L^{-1}(\frac{c}{(s+p)^n})=c\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-pt}
\end{equation*}

This way you find the $x(t)$. Here note that you can get complex numbers as $p$ can be complex. However, as ODE has real coefficients, they come in conjugate pairs and add up to a real function.

Comment: Thanks for the great demonstration. :)

Comment: Glad to help :).